# C# combobox takes the control of whole form

Tags: c#, combobox

[image]I have a form with some textboxes and some other items specially combobox.
When I selected an item from combobox that has label "Land" in screenshot, I can't do anything with other elements in form!
that combobox turns blue (means selected and focused) and user cant fill other boxes!

```
    private void cb_land_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Lands j in lands)
        {
            if (j.landName.Equals(cb_land.Text))
            {
                tb_countrykz.Text = j.landKZ;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

code for fill combobox from database :

```
this.länderTableAdapter.Fill(this.test_tab.länder);
```

I have 3 other combobox in my form and they work fine.
this combobox locks other boxes and does not let user to click on any other elements in form.

Comment: Two Questions: What exactly is länderTableAdapter? And Why to you compare cb_land.Text, instead of cb_land.SelectedItem?

Comment: länderTableAdapter is for getting länder table data from database as a dataset for combobox and cb_land.Text is the only way to get the combobox current text, others don't work!

Comment: If it is filled with string, try selectedItem casted to string. Or else, if it's an object, cast it to this type and read the value you're using for the DisplayMember-propery.